# My Android App Contains InApp Subscription Which Option shoulld i choose in Financial Feature?

Tags: google-play-console

App Content play console In App Subscription should i select other or no option [image]

Comment: In the image, it is saying that Your app provides any finance-related services such as Crypto, insurance, trading, etc. So if your app not provide those features then click on `My app doesn't provide any .....`

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.